# Can do underscore's “intersection” with condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have two arrays. I need to exclude elements from first array by some condition from second array. I don't want to make two loops and check my condition.

I can't find how it do in underscore.

```
angular.forEach(categoryList, function (subcategory) {
  angular.forEach(userPemissions, function (permission) {
    if (permission.AuditCategoryId == subcategory.Id) {
      category.subCategories.push(item);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: [`_.filter()`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) or [`_.reject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject)

Comment: Yes, but I need second array

Comment: You can do what ever you want in the `[predicate]`. You could also set the second array as the `[context]` (`== this`)

Comment: can't understand. Could you please create answer with example ?

Comment: Add an example in your question. Without, there are way to much possibilities to achieve this.

Comment: How do `category` and `item` relate to `categoryList` and `userPermissions`?  Whatever functional transformation you're attempting may be better done at an outer level from what you have here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var list1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo1' }, { id: 2, name: 'foo2' }, { id: 3, name: 'foo3' }];
var list2 = [{ id: 4, name: 'foo4' }, { id: 2, name: 'foo2' }, { id: 5, name: 'foo5' }];

var result = _.filter(list1, function (item1) {
    return _.some(this, function (item2) {
        return item1.id === item2.id;
    });
}, list2);

console.log(result); //[{ id: 2, name: 'foo2' }]
```